# VictoryLegend: how to relatively position (e.g. bottom center)

Tags: victory-charts

I'm using VictoryCharts, specifically the `VictoryLegend` component to render the legend for my chart. According to [the docs](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-legend/) it sounds like the only options for positioning the legend are absolute `x` and `y` coordinates. I'm trying to position the legend relatively, for example "at the bottom in the middle". This is the desired appearance:

[image: legend centered at the bottom of the chart]

Because the series labels in my legend are internationalized, the number of characters and thus the legend's width changes based on locale, so it isn't an option to hard-code an `x` coordinate to center the legend. I would also prefer not to have to calculate the `y` coordinate based on the height of my chart. Is there any way to relatively position the `VictoryLegend` below the chart and horizontally centered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the maintainer in [a Gitter conversation](https://gitter.im/FormidableLabs/victory?at=5a78f6477dcd63481f215b9c), it appears this is not possible:

[image]

Comment: 2022, can't center a legend on the bottom of the chart ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but there's nothing entirely built-in with Victory charts to do it. The library has an amazing amount of flexibility but a terrible dearth of sensible defaults.

To begin, you first have to backfill basic chart responsiveness as outlined here:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/396#issuecomment-773791721

Then you can use the same boundingRect width/height to position the legend as well:

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-fog-f3ed9d?file=/index.js

Or the relevant code pieces here:

```js
const Chart = () => {
  //NOTE victory charts don't automatically resize width ‍♂️ yet - https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/396
  const [boundingRect, setBoundingRect] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  const containerRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setBoundingRect(node.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  }, []);

  //...

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} style={{ width: "90vw", height: "90vh" }}>
      <VictoryChart
        domainPadding={30}
        theme={VictoryTheme.material}
        height={boundingRect.width * 0.9}
        width={boundingRect.width}
      >
        <VictoryBar
          data={chartData}
          cornerRadius={2}
          style={{ data: { fill: ({ datum }) => datum.fill } }}
        />
        <VictoryLegend
          data={legendData}
          centerTitle
          gutter={20}
          itemsPerRow={2}
          orientation="horizontal"
          rowGutter={{ top: 0, bottom: -10 }}
          style={{ title: { fontSize: 20 } }}
          titleOrientation="bottom"
          x={50}
          y={boundingRect.width * 0.81}
        />
      </VictoryChart>
    </div>
  );
};
```